# Is there a way to display number of projects in a view/folder in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

We have a few folder has many projects inside, although I can go to the folder to find the total number of projects, is there to have Jenkins display the total number of projects in the current web page, be a view, or a folder, whatever.